# Get `UIRefreshControl` to north of above `UITableViewController` content, instead of under header?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, ios11, uirefreshcontrol

I've noticed that at least on iOS 11, if you hide the navigation bar on a `UITableViewController`, the `UIRefreshControl` appears *underneath* the header of the content instead of above it in the scroll area.

Screenshot shows the header background set to white and the view background to black to illustrate this contrast:

[image: screenshot of issue]

Is anyone aware of a way to make the `UIRefreshControl` appear north of all of the `UITableViewController` (the black area shown), instead of inside it... consistently for iOS 9, 10, and 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... turned out to be a glitch. Apparently if you hide a navigation bar on iOS 11 (and possibly other versions), it does this. The solution is to take the view out of the `UINavigationController` instead.